# Adding a column with values based on the levels of multiple other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple columns and thousands of rows. I want to add another column, the values in this column will depend upon the levels of 3 other columns (2 of the columns are factors and one is date). I want the new column to be the count of rows in the dataset where 3 of the aforementioned variables are equal to the specified levels.

My original data frame is in the following format (albeit this is a very simplified version):

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Red | 2022-05-16 |
| B | Blue | 2022-05-17 |
| C | Green | 2022-05-18 |
| D | Red | 2022-05-19 |

I don't know how to write a functional code but what I was trying so far was:

```
df$new_col <- NA
df$new_col <- as.numeric(df$new_col)
df$new_col<- nrow(df$Date=="2022-05-16", df$ColumnA=="C", df$ColumnB=="Green")
```

As you can see, I am quite clueless. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you're trying to do two things at once: label the rows that meet your condition, and then count them. You can skip the first two lines and do something like `df$new_col <- with(df, Date == '2022-05-16' & ColumnA == 'C' & ColumnB == 'Green')`. You can then simply compute `sum(df$new_col)` to count all the matching rows.

Comment: With `library(dplyr)` you can do `df = df %>% add_count(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)`, if you want the column to generalize for all combinations of column A,B,C values.

Comment: I didn't explain my query in depth enough I think and the sample dataset was poor. To elaborate: I want to fill in the numeric count in a new column. So say there is a row that matches condition A (3 of the specified levels match) I want the new column to be the count of rows that match the condition in the df. So for the example given, it might say '778' in that row, but then for another grouping of levels (e.g. Date == '2022-05-17' & ColumnA == 'B' & ColumnB =='Red'; it would say how many rows match that criteria - e.g. 490)

Comment: My end goal is to remove all duplicate rows after I have performed this computing for all possibilites. So the new column will tell me how many of that row (rows matching the levels - e.g., 2022-05-16, B, Blue) there was in the original df

Comment: Have you tried the `add_tally` code I posted? That does exactly what you describe. But if your goal is to remove the duplicates and retain the counts then there's an even shorter shortcut in `dplyr`, `df %>% count(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)`. If you need more help or think your example is inadequate, please **edit the question** to improve it.